# Where do I stop grinding level and focus on my gear?

Tags: path-of-exile

I started to play Path of Exile and really enjoy it. I played some games of this kind before so I know the concept. I know that Path of Exile as a level cap of 100. However it is kind of long to reach as I can on the official forum and official game FAQ.

I want to know where I should stop "grinding" experience doing with the stuff I picked up on the ground because I know I'll use something else later and start focusing on having a good gear and maybe use the crafting materials I kept all the way through the dificulties.

For exemple; In diablo 2 when you were between levels 80 and 85 it was a good time to stop grinding and start gearing up.

I'm open to any Math-based or non-math-based answers as well as any experiments you can do!

Comment: I suspect this is heavily opinion or individual playstyle-based. The generic answer is something like "whenever getting a gear upgrade becomes easier than gaining a level, and when continuing gets harder". Unless you're playing hardcore, in which case it's "now".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question will have a different answer depending on what build you are trying to accomplish.

For example, the old 'CI Fire Discharger' would require level 80 or so before being able to effectively respec from HP to CI/ES. Because of this, you would use whatever HP gear you could cheaply find until you got to 80+, and then respec and get expensive gear at the same time. This is of course an example of a build that doesn't become extremely powerful until really late, most other popular builds because powerful much earlier.

As a general rule, a time to focus more on gear would be around level 70, when you are in Merciless Act 3 and are ready to start farming Maps. Although high gear isn't needed to start the early level maps, most people will take a massive gear jump before starting them. Most CI classes will also spec out of HP and into CI at around the 60-70 mark, considering they have the CI gear ready.

Once again though, this all depends on the build you are playing and how you want to approach it as to when XP farming turns to gear farming.